# We have 100 letters: 81-$M$, 10-$B$, 7-$S$ , 2-$H$. How many ways we can choose 4 letters so we can write : $SBBH$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling with this question and here's what I did: 
for example the $S$ letter, we need just one, so what I thought about is doing $100 \choose 7$$7 \choose 1$. (choosing the $7$ letters $S$ then choosing one from them). and it goes like that for the rest of the letters then I add the results up. 
 I feel like I'm making mistakes and I'm not sure of my solution, would appreciate any feedback and tips.

Comment: You don't choose from $100$ because it's already given as distinct letters. You also don't add them up rather you would multiply them up.

Comment: Try to choose each letter from its group, so if you want to choose $S$ just choose it from the $7$ that you have. Do this for each letter. Be careful if you are doing it with/without repetition.

Answer (score 3):

You need an S $7 \choose 1$, two B $10 \choose 2$ and one H $2 \choose 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask how do you know that the other letters don't affect my ways of choosing the desired letters? it's a problem for me in many questions and would appreciate any tips

Comment: Because you only choose 4 letters